# Sympy Integration returns 1.0*Integral(..)

Tags: python, sympy, numerical-integration, astronomy

Whenever I try and use Sympy to Integrate my Function, it doesn't evaluate it but simply returns my input multiplied by 1.0.

Here is my code:

```
import sympy as sp

a = sp.Symbol('a')

Ωm = 0.31
Ωr = 9*(10**(-5))
ΩΛ = 0.69
Ω0 = Ωm + Ωr + ΩΛ


I = sp.integrate(((Ωm*a**(-1)) + (Ωr*a**(-2)) + (ΩΛ*a**(2)) + (1-Ω0))**(-0.5),a)
print(I)
```

Here is the answer I get:

```
1.0*Integral((0.69*a**2 - 8.99999999999235e-5 + 0.31/a + 9.0e-5/a**2)**(-0.5), a)
```

Where am I going wrong? Is this an integral beyond the capacity of Sympy? If so does anyone know any better ways to evaluate that integral. The limits are 0 and a by the way.

Answer (score 1):

When SymPy returns an integral unevaluated, that means that it doesn't know how to compute it.

In this case, the integrand is an algebraic function, which SymPy often has a difficult time with integrating.

Answer (score -1):

Your code works fine. Result of the integration is non-convergent integral. You could print it in more beautiful form (in `jupyter`) with following code

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing(wrap_line=False, no_global=True)

a = sp.Symbol('a')

Ωm = 0.31
Ωr = 9*(10**(-5))
ΩΛ = 0.69
Ω0 = Ωm + Ωr + ΩΛ


I = sp.integrate(((Ωm*a**(-1)) + (Ωr*a**(-2)) + (ΩΛ*a**(2)) + (1-Ω0))**(-0.5),a)
I
```

results

￼[image]

Answer (score -1):

I ran the integral on [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B((0.31)%2F(a)%2B(9*10%5E(-5))%2F(a%5E(2))%2B0.69a%5E(2)%2B1-0.31-9*10%5E(-5)-0.69)%5E(-.5)da,0,a%5D)  and it says it doesn't converge (the computation takes a while, so unless you have a wolfram premium account it might not complete):

Try out an integral you know converges.

So try out something like

```
import sympy as sp

sp.init_printing(wrap_line=False, no_global=True)
a = sp.Symbol('a')

I = sp.integrate(a**3,a)
```

You should get a**4/4